# new stage 1 clutch slipping after upgrading mag size?

Tags: ford, clutch, mustang, rear-differential

~I installed a stage 1 clutch kit on my 07 Mustang v6.

As long as the mags are 17's there is no issue, but as soon as I went to 18" with sticky pirelli's... the brand new clutch slips and over revs in 1st gear under hard acceleration.

It does not do it if I "pop" the clutch, only if I try to be smooth so I do not spin the wheel... (no lsd)

Also I have tried it with traction control on and off and it only seems to do it when it's off.

The car is lowered 1.25".

The transmission was rebuilt by experts.

I suspect that the tires may have too much grip and the mags might be to heavy for the rear diff gearing... could this be the case?

Comment: Did you get the same behaviour with the previous clutch? Or, is there a problem with this clutch - pressure plate weak, oil contamination etc?

Comment: No the previous clutch was fine... as a matter of fact it was an OEM German brand and it seemed to bite better the the one I have now. There is only one strange thing... the first time I start the car up the clutch peddle seems to be down half way... I lift it with my foot and then it's fine... I have bled the system when I replaced 2 callipers and the clutch switch was replaced... very mysterious

Comment: Deconstruction of the clutch kit: Flywheel, clutch plate, pressure plate, master cylinder, new flywheel bolts.  The brake fluid is a hi temp one because I brake very hard at times. I upgraded the front disks to GT discs and breaks and have braided stainless lines... I also replaced the power booster and as far as I know there are no leaks anywhere or oil stains on the ground when I move the car.

Comment: How did you break the new clutch in? How many miles? What type of driving to break it in?

Comment: Super-sticky tires may make the clutch the weak point. Did you replace the throw out bearing when you installed the clutch?

Comment: Yes the throw out bearing is new.

Comment: If you're trying to accelerate when the clutch is partially engaged - your foot is on the pedal - you'll slip the clutch. The old tires may have been crappy enough that they slipped before the clutch did. If you get it into gear and off the clutch in 1st, and then romp on i - WITHOUT your foot on or near the clutch pedal - does it slip, or just accelerate? And stop popping your clutch if you like your car.

Comment: What are "mags" ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try bracing the brake pedal down next time you park it for a while. If the clutch pedal isn't half down after that then you'll know you have an issue in the line pressures(probably too much pressure) There's no clutch adjustment to get wrong, or tweak with the setup where they have the hydraulic system running off the brake system in those. The sunken pedal seems to be your best piece of evidence to go on though. I'd suspect the tc being turned on eleminates the problem because of it's effect on the hydraulic pressures not because of the actual function. I've seen comparably simple brake systems without additional hydraulic systems running off them that required 3-4 attempts at bleeding by highly qualified professionals, and you obviously got it extremely close if it doesn't cause issues except for in one very specific set of circumstances and parts combination. Chances are you have some type of contaminants, water, or air in the lines or it's just overfilled.

Comment: I will attempt this...Thanks guys for all your help.

Comment: had the brakes bled by a performance pro using a vacuum method -  no joy!